# Why is jsfiddle giving me the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I'm using structured javascript code and it works fine on my computer. But when I add it to jsFiddle, it gives me the followinge error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

My code looks like this:

```
var StentGallery = {
    gallery: null,

    init : function(){
            this.gallery = jQuery('#gallery-list-ui');
            this.resizeImage();
        }
    }
    (...)
}
```

Does anyone know why this is not working in jsFiddle?
See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/smyhbckx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your code:

```
var StentGallery = {
    gallery: null,

    init : function(){
           this.gallery = jQuery('#gallery-list-ui');
           this.resizeImage();
           } // <----- this is prematurely closing your object
    }, 

    resizeImage: function(){
    ...
```

To fix this, simply remove that bracket:

```
var StentGallery = {
    gallery: null,

    init : function(){
           this.gallery = jQuery('#gallery-list-ui');
           this.resizeImage();
    },

    resizeImage: function(){
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that after I stripped my code in the fiddle.

Comment: @Steven Glad I could help!

Comment: Don't forget the 2 missing ';' after your $img.css calls.

Comment: @Mr_Pouet JavaScript will implicitly add those semicolons, however it is good practice to always include them yourself so nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

There's an extra closing '}' for your init function.